# Add yes if within a group, a column contains all element from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
The_list=["A","B"]
```

- 

```
Groups COL2
G1     A
G1     B
G1     C
G2     A
G2     D
G3     A
G3     B
G4     A
G5     B
```

and I would like to add another `COL3` column where I put **yes** for each `Groups` where all element from The_list are present within the `COL2`, and no if not.

I should then get :

```
Groups COL2 COL3
G1     A    yes
G1     B    yes
G1     C    yes
G2     A    no
G2     D    no
G3     A    yes
G3     B    yes
G4     A    no
G5     B    no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`set intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
# Group on column 'Groups' and apply set intersection and find length of set
In [1178]: out = df.groupby('Groups')['COL2'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & set(The_list))).reset_index()

# If length of set is equal to the length of the list, then 'yes' else 'no'
In [1179]: import numpy as np
In [1180]: out['COL3'] = np.where(out.COL2.eq(len(The_list), 'yes', 'no')

# Merge original df with above and populate COL3
In [1185]: df = df.merge(out[['Groups','COL3']])

In [1186]: df
Out[1186]: 
  Groups COL2 COL3
0     G1    A  yes
1     G1    B  yes
2     G1    C  yes
3     G2    A   no
4     G2    D   no
5     G3    A  yes
6     G3    B  yes
7     G4    A   no
8     G5    B   no
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that Groups is the index. If not:

```
df = df.set_index("Groups")
```

Initialize COL3:

```
df["COL3"] = "yes"
```

Then make a list of the COL2 values for each group and change COL3 to "no" if an element from the list is missing:

```
for group in set(df.index):  
    COL2_values = list(df.loc[group, "COL2"])
    
    for element in The_list:
        if element not in COL2_values:
            df.loc[group, "COL3"] = 'no'
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df
'''
  Groups COL2
0     G1    A
1     G1    B
2     G1    C
3     G2    A
4     G2    D
5     G3    A
6     G3    B
7     G4    A
8     G5    B
'''
```

```
The_list=["A","B"]
tag = df.groupby('Groups').apply(lambda x: all([i in x.COL2.to_list() for i in The_list]))

tag
'''
Groups
G1     True
G2    False
G3     True
G4    False
G5    False
dtype: bool
'''
```

```
df.assign(COL3=df.Groups.map(tag).map({True:'yes', False:'no'}))
'''
  Groups COL2 COL3
0     G1    A  yes
1     G1    B  yes
2     G1    C  yes
3     G2    A   no
4     G2    D   no
5     G3    A  yes
6     G3    B  yes
7     G4    A   no
8     G5    B   no
'''
```